# Text editor with predefined search-replace pairs

Tags: text-editor

I need a text editor (preferably for Windows) that can record a few search-replace pairs - so I can have them predefined - and then, when I open the replace dialog (many editors have it on Ctrl+H), then I can simply choose between one of the predefined pairs, instead of entering the search and the replace texts.

Maybe there is a better term than "predefined search-replace pairs" but this is the best term I know for this.

Comment: Do you insist on exactly that mechanism? If not, you should be able to manage the functionality in pretty much any editor that supports macros...

Comment: Most text editors remember what you entered there. [NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) certainly has a history, and that's generally reckoned to be the best.

Comment: Indeed, I tried Notepad++ and it works very nice using macros - also I can assign hotkeys for them, and that's awesome.

Answer (score 2):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor (free) has this feature in the **FindInFiles** plugin.

- Install FindInFiles from menu Plugins/ AddonManager/ Install
- Open it: Plugins/ Find in Files
- Show "Replace with" field: menu item "= / Show Replace with"
- Fill "Find what" and "Replace with" fields with text
- Save preset by using menu: "= / Presets/ Save preset as"

[image: CudaText]

Later you can recall any presets by menu: "= / Presets".

Comment: Thanks, I need something like this, but only for the current file. This one doesn't save the "Find what:" and "Replace with:" fields in the presets though. Unfortunately, it only saves the "In files:" and "In folder:" fields. It is very good that it has hotkeys for the presets but I need those shortcuts to work from the main window, not only from the plugin window. Also it would be very nice to start replacing already when I push the hotkey, instead of just restoring up the preset.